# EXcel VBA : Excel Macro to create table in a PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

My requirement is I have a Excel which contains some data. I would like to select some data from the excel and open a PowerPoint file and

**Create Table in PowerPoint and populate the data in to it**

Right now I have succeeded in collecting the data from excel opening a PowerPoint file through Excel VBA Code.

Code for Opening the PowerPoint from Excel.

```
    Set objPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.application")
    objPPT.Visible = True
    Dim file As String
    file = "C:\Heavyhitters_new.ppt"
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(file)
```

Now how do I create the table in PowerPoint from Excel and populate the data.

Timely help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some code from http://mahipalreddy.com/vba.htm

```
''# Code by Mahipal Padigela
''# Open Microsoft Powerpoint,Choose/Insert a Table type Slide(No.4), then double click to add a...
''# ...Table(3 Cols & 2 Rows) then rename the Table to "Table1", Save and Close the Presentation
''# Open Microsoft Excel, add some test data to Sheet1(This example assumes that you have some data in...
''# ... Rows 1,2 and Columns 1,2,3)
''# Open VBA editor(Alt+F11),Insert a Module and Paste the following code in to the code window
''# Reference 'Microsoft Powerpoint Object Library' (VBA IDE-->tools-->references)
''# Change "strPresPath" with full path of the Powerpoint Presentation created earlier.
''# Change "strNewPresPath" to where you want to save the new Presnetation to be created later
''# Close VB Editor and run this Macro from Excel window(Alt+F8) 

Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim SlideNum As Integer
Sub PPTableMacro()
    Dim strPresPath As String, strExcelFilePath As String, strNewPresPath As String
    strPresPath = "H:\PowerPoint\Presentation1.ppt"
    strNewPresPath = "H:\PowerPoint\new1.ppt"

    Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue
    Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)
    SlideNum = 1
    oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
    Set oPPTShape = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("Table1")

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    oPPTShape.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(1, 1).Text
    oPPTShape.Table.Cell(1, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(1, 2).Text
    oPPTShape.Table.Cell(1, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(1, 3).Text
    oPPTShape.Table.Cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(2, 1).Text
    oPPTShape.Table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(2, 2).Text
    oPPTShape.Table.Cell(2, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(2, 3).Text

    oPPTFile.SaveAs strNewPresPath
    oPPTFile.Close
    oPPTApp.Quit

    Set oPPTShape = Nothing
    Set oPPTFile = Nothing
    Set oPPTApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "Presentation Created", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: This was useful too some extend... I have completed it.. thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5):

This Excel-VBA exports the selected range from Excel to a PowerPoint native table. It also works with merged cells.

```
Sub Export_Range()

    Dim pp As New PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim shpTable As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet

    Set rng = Selection

    pp.Visible = True
    If pp.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
        Set ppt = pp.Presentations.Add
    Else
        Set ppt = pp.ActivePresentation
    End If

    Set sld = ppt.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    Set shpTable = sld.Shapes.AddTable(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            shpTable.Table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
                rng.Cells(i, j).Text
        Next
    Next

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            If (rng.Cells(i, j).MergeArea.Cells.Count > 1) And _
                (rng.Cells(i, j).Text <> "") Then
                shpTable.Table.Cell(i, j).Merge _
                shpTable.Table.Cell(i + rng.Cells(i, j).MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1, _
                j + rng.Cells(i, j).MergeArea.Columns.Count - 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next

    sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
        rng.Worksheet.Name & " - " & rng.Address

End Sub
```