# Insert date from a cell in Excel to a line in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I manage several PowerPoint files. When a revision is made, the date is changed on an Excel file to keep a record but also needs to be changed manually on the first slide of the PowerPoint file.

We manage all of the revision dates for the PowerPoints in a column of an Excel file. We are having issues with people forgetting to change the date in the PowerPoint file and I would like to have this automated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760629/exporting-data-from-excel-to-an-existing-powerpoint-slide-using-vba that may help you

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 ways to make this happen:

### -**The easy way:**

Copy and paste excel table into Powerpoint, make sure you choose Paste Special> Paste Link.[image: PPT PasteSpecial Excel Table]

(http://www.thinkoutsidetheslide.com/automatic-updating-of-excel-tables-in-powerpoint-slides/)
Users will then need to click update links every time the PPT or PPTX opens and all should be  well. A little hack here is to choose the following in Excel before you copy. View > Uncheck Headings and Uncheck Gridlines. This will make your linked table in Powerpoint appear less Excel Like.... [image: Excel Headings]

### -**The hard way:**

If you have the kind of users who will never ever click update. Create a Macro to fire when the first slide is actioned in some way, usually through a button. This is because Powerpoint unlike Excel cannot automatically fire VBA code on opening. So you need this  workaround (http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00741_How_can_I_get_my_code_to_run_automatically_when_a_presentation_opens-.htm).

Comment: Re -The hard way:  That'll only work when the user starts a slide show; it won't work when they simply open the file.  On the other hand an addin that traps file open or save or close events could easily update a date in the PPT file w/o even needing to mess with Excel.